# Azure failing to update hostname bindings

Tags: azure, dns

I had no problems since today i've added almost 18 domains properly but now i am getting an error "failed to update hostname bindings". 
I removed one domain and tried to add again and i had the same issue. So it is not because of domain settings that domain was already added normally.

Comment: I'm getting this issue too - I have four sites on a subscription, one successfully using an external domain, and now I'm trying to add an external domain to a second of the sites, but I'm getting that error message, even though we've set up both sites exactly the same.

Comment: We have over 100 web apps running and are experiencing the same thing. Seems to be something that just started today. Nice post saved me from pulling my hair out. Thanks for the suggestion to use old panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have it too in preview portal (portal.azure.com), but it works in the old portal (manage.windowsazure.com)

Comment: The problem is the old panel doesnt allow someone who doesnt own the subscription to edit the bindings.

Comment: Here we are 9 months later and I was still getting the error on the portal when I tried today. However when I went to 'manage' the new hostname was already showing up. Went back to portal and it was showing up there as well. So bottom line for me was that it worked, it just reported that it had failed.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to purchase  domain name in the old portal now directs you to the new portal.  Infuriating!